# Searching through keys dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can i search through a bunch of keys in a Dictionary with a for loop or something like it and see if there is any key with the same first three string values as another string. the following example isnt Code at all but it is basicly the result i whant.

```
Key1(3932030)
Key2(4201230)
Key3(5209872)

ArrayWithKeys(3930000,4200000,5200000)

Dictionary searchForkeys(ArrayWithKeys[i])


keyFound(3932030)
```

Comment: `if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("myString")) {...}`

Comment: but i wanna basicly substring it so i donjt wanna see if its the same key

Comment: like i wanna see if the Keys in my Dictionary at some point in the three first letters is equals to a substring of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Get substring to search and then use it to find keys inside dictionary object.

```cs
string[] keyArray = new string[]{ "3930000", "4200000" , "5200000"};

string substringToSearch ;

foreach(string inputKey in keyArray)
{
    substringToSearch = inputKey.Length >= 3 ? inputKey.Substring(0, 3) : inputKey;

    if(dictionaryObject.Keys.Any(x => x.StartsWith(substringToSearch)))
    {
        // below is the key matched with inputKey
        dictionaryObject.Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith(substringToSearch)).First().Value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Using only for loop

```cs
string substringToSearch = inputKey.Length >= 3 ? inputKey.Substring(0, 3) : inputKey;

for(int i; i < dictionaryObject.Keys.Count; i++)
{       
    if( dictionaryObject.ElementAt(i).Key.StartsWith(substringToSearch) )
    {
        // key matched with inputKey
        // below is key
        string keyStr = dictionaryObject.ElementAt(i).Key;
    }
}
```

Comment: so i could basicly for loop through all the dictionarykeys and ask if there three first numbers are == strings first three numbers

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. I will add a simplified code in some time